# FileoutputStream creating empty files occasionally

Tags: java, file, fileoutputstream

Below code sometimes work as expected and other times creates empty files without writing into them or write part of the buffer creating smaller file. What have I done wrong here? Here I mentioned sometimes because successive calls do either of them. The code is to download a file from a server. Each time the readSize shows it has read the expected amount from the stream. But not always they are written in to the file.

```
    byte[] bytes = new byte[socket.getSendBufferSize()];

    long readSize = 0;
    int length = 0;
    System.out.println(fileSize);
    while (readSize < fileSize
            && (length = socket.getInputStream().read(bytes)) != -1) {

        fileOutputStream.write(bytes, 0, length);
        readSize += length;
        fileOutputStream.flush();
    }

    fileOutputStream.flush();
    fileOutputStream.close();
    socket.close();
```

Comment: Where is the data coming from? i.e. what is the socket connecting to? Have you stepped through the code in the debugger to see whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Files are empty as `while` condition is false.

Add `System.out.println("Inside WHILE")` inside `while` loop and check when file is empty.. You won't see `Inside WHILE` when files is empty and vice-versa.